# Java-simple-serial-connector trows exception UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java

I downloaded the sources from [here](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector). This is the code with wich I am trying to open com port 13.

I saw in the device menager that com port13 is present.

```
import jssc.*;

public class Main {
    static boolean s = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SerialPort ser = new SerialPort("COM1");
        try {
            s = ser.openPort();
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Riko Stana neshto");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println("Riko" + ser.getPortName()  );
    }
}
```

When ran in Eclipse this appears in the console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:                   jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Ljava/lang/String;Z)J
>
> at jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Native Method)
>       at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:158)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:9)

The linbrary consist of java files and two dll file. I linked the java files to my eclipse project, but not sure how they are linked to the dll files. Should I do something in order to link the .java files to the .dll files? Could it be the cause of my problem? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You have downloaded sources or maybe the distributed jssc.jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the JSSC zip here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/downloads
2. Extract jssc.jar in your project folder.
3. Add the "jssc.jar" to your classpath as a .jar library.
4. Optional: Extract javadoc/jssc-2.7.0-javadoc.jar and javadoc/jssc-2.7.0-src.jar in your project folder and add them as javadoc and sources respectively.

Problem solved.

Edit - pitcure:
[image: 1]

Comment: It works, but how? :)
It doesn't have DLLs, only C++  source files. Does it mean that it compiles them somehow before use them?

Comment: @Hairi I studied the code and the dll files are stored inside the jssc.jar, which extracts them on the first stratup inside your user's folder (C:\Users\<username>\.jssc).